# Why do I always get false in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
trouve(id:number):boolean{  
    var bool :boolean =false
    this.comapanyService.query().subscribe((resula)=>{
           for (let i = 0; i < resula.json.length; i++) {
               try {
             if( id == resula.json[i].user.id)
                 {
   console.log('id-user:',id ,'user in company:',resula.json[i].user.id,'company :',resula.json[i].id )
                     bool = true
                   }
                } 
               catch (error) {}
           }
           console.log('bool fin pour :',bool)
      })
      console.log(bool)
      if(bool) return true;else return false
  }

 confirmDelete(login) {
    this.userService.find(login).subscribe((response)=>{
         const id =response.id
        console.log('resulta :', this.trouve(id))
    })
}
```

- resulta : false
- id-user: 7202
- user in company: 7202 company : 5151
- bool fin pour : true

Why do I always get a `false`?

Comment: Your function is async.This line `console.log(bool);` working before results.

Comment: the function trouve()  must return true if she find user but she return false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this.comapanyService.query() is an async operation and takes a little bit. That means the lines below will always get executed before the result comes in (when the bool value was not changed, yet):

```
var bool :boolean =false
console.log(bool)
if(bool) return true;else return false


*oh now we have an answer*
do other stuff inside the subscribe
```